# Stage whisper-dominated plays

Tags: history-of-literature, theater

Among plays that have been written and performed before an audience, what is the largest proportion of any play script that is directed to be performed in stage whispers?

I'm interested to know if there are any plays that are directed to be performed, either in their majority or entirety, in stage whispers.

I'm aware of the stage whisper as a device to "let the audience in" on a character's internal monologue, but I'm looking for plays that use the stage whisper in a more expanded capacity. This might include the excessive, plot-dominating whispered address of the audience by characters, or the stage whisper deployed as a device to signal privileged communications *between characters*.

Comment: I've edited this question to bring it on-topic while (I think) still preserving it in such a way that a correct answer to the new version of the question will give you what you wanted to know in the original version. With that, I've also reopened it to make it available for answering.